# AngularJS Search & Show More Results

Tags: javascript, angularjs, search, filter

I have a problem with my angular search & show more button, sometimes the show-more-button hides, sometimes not. 
I created a little plunker so you can see what i mean, just search a few things (like "nav" or "ios") and click on the button to see my problem [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fpF58AiZsq13i8AK1qU7?p=preview)

```
<div class="show-more-wrapper">
<button class="show-more-btn" ng-hide="results.length === labs.length" ng-click="limit = limit +3">Mehr anzeigen...</button>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Because your images is taking time to load, after images load your more button goes down

Comment: Seems to be working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your ng-show will show if the number of results is equal to the number of labs. That will never be true if the number of results (including pagination) is less than the number of labs.

The correct logic, following your code, would be this one:

```
<div class="show-more-wrapper">
    <button class="show-more-btn" ng-hide="results.length === (labs | filter:search).length" ng-click="limit = limit +3">Mehr anzeigen...</button>
</div>
```

If the number of results shown is equal to the number of records found by the filter... there is nothing more to look for.

Forked [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/diwBDZpXxfRcZfp8YmVk?p=preview)